# Execute a code after login check in Symfony2

Tags: authentication, symfony

Symfony2 provides a very simple tool for user login. In practice, the framework do all the security controls for you. As shown in the [official doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html), a controller (*SecurityController*) can be used to load the login form page. Then, a route is associated to **login check** the input provided by the user through the login form. If the login is correct, the user is redirected to the home page (or another one); otherwise, the user must re-enter username and password.

Since I need to load in the session some user preference from a database, I want to know if there is a way to execute such a function once the login check ascertained the correctness of the user login.
Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to write your own `AuthenticationHandler` which will implement two interfaces below:

```
class AuthenticationHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface
```

In that handler you should define method `onAuthenticationSuccess()`

Inside this method you can do whatever you need.

Don't forget also to set your listener in `security.yml`

```
firewalls:
    main:
        ....
        your_form_login:
            ...
            success_handler: your.authentication_handler
```

Check also this [useful doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html)

Comment: Ok, I found [this nice example](http://blog.alterphp.com/2011/10/set-up-authenticationsuccesshandler.html). Thanks...