# Symfony2 custom AuthenticationSuccessHandler and user redirection

Tags: redirect, authentication, symfony

With [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901978/execute-a-code-after-login-check-in-symfony2), it has been clarified how to execute code after the login in a Symfony2 application. In particular, the solution is to write an `AuthenticationHandler` which implement the interface `AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface`.

Stated that, in the function `onAuthenticationSuccess()` from interface `AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface`, one has to specify the uri to which the user will be redirected after the login.

By default, when a user try to access a secured area (i.e. **page X**), Symfony2 redirect the user to the login page. When the login success, the user is redirected to the secured **page X**. Hence, there is no a unique page after login (e.g. the home).

How to handle with `onAuthenticationSuccess()` function to redirect the user to **page X**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented this solution.
1) save the URI in the session in each visited page (with exception of the login page).
2) load the URI in `onAuthenticationSuccess()` function to return it in a `RedirectResponse()`.

To accomplish point 1), two steps are required:
First)
Assuming that a base template has been defined, put the following code where you want (e.g., also before `<html>` tag:

```
{% block setcurrenturi %}
    {{ setCurrentURI(app.session, app.request.uri) }}
{% endblock %}
```

This code requires a function to be defined in you Twig Extension (assuming you have implemented a *Twig Extension*). The function is very simple:

```
public static function setCurrentURI($session, $URI) {
    $session->set('LAST_URI', $URI);
}
```

Then, go to the Twig template of your login form page and redefine the block as:

```
{% block setcurrenturi %}
{% endblock %}
```

In this way, the URI of the login page is not saved in session.

Now, in the `onAuthenticationSuccess()` function put the following line:

```
  return new RedirectResponse($request->getSession()->get('LAST_URI'));
```

Comment: Yes, but in this way I don't get the destination URI, only the starting one. It would be nice to get also the final URI. Think about an anonymous user that click on a button which requires to be logged. Actually, the user click the button, then it is sent to the login page, and finally it is sent back to the button page: the button action is not performed and the user has to press it again.